# How to set the NGINX Proxy network to wikijs correct?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the NGINY Proxy (with GUI) installed and the Proxy woks fine. At next I will install wikijs with docker-compose. I get the error message:

```
ERROR: for wikijs_wiki_1  Cannot start service wiki: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint wikijs_wiki_1 (063488ca46a3bfe192519ee3a6dcb0cb8f22a3dc36f7bb4f08a07d488f127308): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated
```

Port 80 will be used from the NGINX Proxy. I think that I have to use the docker network to connect Wikijs with the NGINX Proxy.

docker network list

```
11a33c25b126   bridge                 bridge    local
679e6fd394bd   host                   host      local
76ace32703bc   none                   null      local
f2da18a27140   reverseproxy           bridge    local
787bc5cf1faf   reverseproxy_default   bridge    local
```

The question is how do I set the networks correct in the docker-compose.yml, that wikijs starts without an error?

Here the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DBNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DBPASSWD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DBUSER}
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  wiki:
    image: requarks/wiki:2
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: ${DBUSER}
      DB_PASS: ${DBPASSWD}
      DB_NAME: ${DBNAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:3000"

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  reverseproxy_default:
```

Answer (score 1):

check your using port
with command:

netstat -lntp

and check nginx.conf;

server {

```
    listen 80;

    location / {
         proxy_pass <<you're wiki.js>>;
```

maybe 80 port is already used

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change the ports entry from

```
ports:
    -80:80
```

to

```
ports:
     -3000:3000
```